# USD to EU conversion / paypal

Tags: paypal

I just developed a PHP shopping cart here :

http://dooweet.org/fr/store/

The problem is that, when i want to order it via paypal, paypal transforms my EUROS into USD... I don't find my problem in the code during the sending request.

How can i force paypal to recieve the checkout into EUROS and not DOLLARS please ?

Comment: Is your paypal set to accept only USD? Check settings on paypal

Answer (score 0):

Set your Paypal account default currency to EUR